# PySpark TypeErrors

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Writing a simple CSV to Parquet conversion.

CSV file has a couple of Timestamps in it.  Therefore I am getting type errors when I try to write.

To work around that, I tried implementing this line to identify the timestamp cols and perform a to_timestamp on them.

```
rdd = sc.textFile("../../../Downloads/test_type.csv").map(lambda line: [to_timestamp(i) if instr(i,"-")==5 else i for i in line.split(",")])
```

Getting this error:

```
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/yy/xx/Documents/gg/csv_to_parquet/csv_to_parquet.py", line 55, in <lambda>
    rdd = sc.textFile("../../../test/test.csv").map(lambda line: [to_timestamp(i) if (instr(i,"-")==5) else i for i in line.split(",")])

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

Any idea how to pull this off?

==========================================

## Version 2

Made some progress today, I am writing the parquet file now, but when I query the data I get a Binary data vs timestamp data error:

```
HIVE_BAD_DATA: Field header__timestamp's type BINARY in parquet is incompatible with type timestamp defined in table schema
```

I modified the code to use all StringTypes initially and then modified the datatypes in the dataframe.

```py
    sc = SparkContext(appName="CSV2Parquet")
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

    schema = StructType\
    ([
        StructField("header__change_seq", StringType(), True),
        StructField("header__change_oper", StringType(), True),
        StructField("header__change_mask", StringType(), True),
        StructField("header__stream_position", StringType(), True),
        StructField("header__operation", StringType(), True),
        StructField("header__transaction_id", StringType(), True),
        StructField("header__timestamp", StringType(), True),
        StructField("l_en_us", StringType(), True),
        StructField("priority", StringType(), True),
        StructField("typecode", StringType(), True),
        StructField("retired", StringType(), True),
        StructField("name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("id", StringType(), True),
        StructField("description", StringType(), True),
        StructField("l_es_ar", StringType(), True),
        StructField("adw_updated_ts", StringType(), True),
        StructField("adw_process_id", StringType(), True)
        ])

   rdd = sc.textFile("../../../Downloads/pctl_jobdatetype.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(","))

    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
    df2 = df.withColumn('header__timestamp', df['header__timestamp'].cast('timestamp'))
    df2 = df.withColumn('adw_updated_ts', df['adw_updated_ts'].cast('timestamp'))
    df2 = df.withColumn('priority', df['priority'].cast('double'))
    df2 = df.withColumn('id', df['id'].cast('double'))

    df2.write.parquet('../../../Downloads/input-parquet')
```

Sample Data:

```
"header__change_seq","header__change_oper","header__change_mask","header__stream_position","header__operation","header__transaction_id","header__timestamp","l_en_us","priority","typecode","retired","name","id","description","l_es_ar","adw_updated_ts","adw_process_id"
,"I",,,"IDL",,"1970-01-01 00:00:01.000","Effective Date","10.0","Effective","0","Effective Date","10001.0","Effective Date","Effective Date","2020-02-16 15:45:07.432","fb69d6f6-06fa-4c93-b8d6-bb7c7229ee88"
,"I",,,"IDL",,"1970-01-01 00:00:01.000","Written Date","20.0","Written","0","Written Date","10002.0","Written Date","Written Date","2020-02-16 15:45:07.432","fb69d6f6-06fa-4c93-b8d6-bb7c7229ee88"
,"I",,,"IDL",,"1970-01-01 00:00:01.000","Reference Date","30.0","Reference","0","Reference Date","10003.0","Reference Date","Reference Date","2020-02-16 15:45:07.432","fb69d6f6-06fa-4c93-b8d6-bb7c7229ee88"
```

Comment: can you show how ur data looks like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I modified the dataframe name to df2 for lines 3-6 below, seems to be working fine, and Athena is also returning results.

```py
    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
    df2 = df.withColumn('header__timestamp', df['header__timestamp'].cast('timestamp'))
    df2 = df2.withColumn('adw_updated_ts', df['adw_updated_ts'].cast('timestamp'))
    df2 = df2.withColumn('priority', df['priority'].cast('double'))
    df2 = df2.withColumn('id', df['id'].cast('double'))
    df2.write.parquet('../../../Downloads/input-parquet')
```